# Clarifying Example 16 in Gallian, Chapter 14: Factor Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm currently reading through Gallian, and I'm struggling on Example 16 in Chapter 14 (Ideals and Factor Rings). It follows like this:

> The ideal $\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ is maximal in $\mathbb R[x]$. To see this, assume that $A$ is an ideal of $\mathbb R[x]$ that properly contains $\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$. We will prove that $A = \mathbb R[x]$ by showing that $A$ contains some nonzero real number $c$. (This is the constant polynomial $h(x) = c$ for all $x$.) Then $1 = c(1/c) \in A$ and therefore, by Exercise 19, $A = \mathbb R[x]$.

Exercise 19 was asking if $A$ is an ideal of a ring $R$ and $1 \in A$, then $A = R$, which I had no problem with proving. However, its past this that I start to get confused:

> To this end, let $f(x) \in A$ but $f(x) \not\in \langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$. Then
> $$f(x) = q(x)(x^2 + 1) + r(x)$$
> where $0 \leq \deg(r(x)) < 2$ and $r(x) \neq 0$. Then $r(x) = ax + b$ where $a, b \neq 0$, and
> $$ax + b + r(x) = f(x) - q(x)(x^2 + 1) \in A$$

I'm assuming that this is a typo since he seemed to just pull out that $2r(x) = f(x) - q(x)(x^2 + 1)$. I want to say that this is supposed to be $ax + b = r(x) = f(x) - q(x)(x^2 + 1)$, unless I'm missing something. But then he suddenly claims this:

> $$a^2x^2 - b^2 = (ax + b)(ax - b) \in A \text{ and } a^2(x^2 + 1) \in A$$
> So
> $$0 \neq a^2 + b^2 = (a^2x^2 + a^2) - (a^2x^2 - b^2) \in A$$

My two issues are this: why do we need to do this in the first place? How does this relate to $\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ being a maximal ideal? As far as definitions go, I only know that maximal ideals are ideals $A$ such that if $B$ is an ideal of some commutative ring $R$, then $B = A$ or $B = R$ (I actually sort of struggle with this definition as well, so some elucidation may be helpful).

I'm also struggling where $(ax - b)(ax + b)$ came from. Is this because $x^2 = -1$? But then we only get $a^2x^2 - b^2 = -a^2 - b^2$, and I have no idea where this fact will be used to show that $\langle x^2 + 1 \rangle$ is a maximal ideal. I appreciate the help!

Comment: The typo is indeed that it should be $ax+b {\color{red}=}r(x) = f(x)-q(x)(x^2+1)\in A$.

Comment: Your description of "maximal ideal" is incomplete/confused. $A$ is a maximal ideal *of $R$* if and only if for every ideal $B$ of $R$, if $A\subseteq B\subseteq R$, then $A=B$ or $B=R$. As to "where $(ax-b)(ax+b)$ came from", it came from finding some multiple of $ax+b$ that will "work" to produce a nonzero element in the ideal. The rest of the calculation shows that under your assumption, you can conclude that both $a^2x^2+a^2$ lies in $A$, and that $a^2x^2-b^2$ lies in $A$, and therefore so does their difference; the difference is the nonzero real $a^2+b^2$.

Comment: And as the first paragraph tells you, the fact that you have found a nonzero constant in the ideal $A$ means that $A=R=\mathbb{R}[x]$. Thus you have proven that if $A$ is an ideal of $R$, $\langle x^2+1\rangle\subseteq A\subseteq R$, and $\langle x^2+1\rangle \neq A$, then $A=R$. This proves that $\langle x^2+1\rangle$ satisfies the definition of maximal ideal; i.e., that it is a maximal ideal. (remember that "P or Q" is equivalent to "if not P, then Q")

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for the typo clarification.

Thank you for the extra description on the maximal ideal. However, how do we know that $ax - b \in A$ to conclude that $a^2x^2 - b^2 \in A$?

Lastly, does it matter that it is simply a nonzero constant, or does it have to be 1? Would I be correct in that Exercise 19 is asking us that if the unit of a ring $R$ is in the ideal $A$, then $A = R$?

Comment: We do not need $ax-b$ to be in $A$. Remember that $A$ is an ideal, and we already know it contains $ax+b$. That means it also contains every multiple of $ax+b$, and therefore contains $(ax+b)(ax-b)$. Because $a^2+b^2\in\mathbb{R}$ is nonzero, it has a multiplicative inverse which is an element of $\mathbb{R}\subseteq\mathbb{R}[x]$. If $A$ contains $a^2+b^2$, being an ideal it also contains every multiple of $a^2+b^2$, and $1$ is a multiple of $a^2+b^2$ in this ring.